# How do I populate gridview based on dropdownlist selected value using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, drop-down-menu, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to populate grid based on dropdownlist selected value: my c# coding is

```
protected void atddroplist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      empatdListBI c = new empatdListBI();
      DbConnection b = new DbConnection();
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();


      if (atddroplist.SelectedIndex == 1)
      {
         b.OpenConnection();
         dt = c.LoadRecords(empText.Text);
         GridView1.DataSource = dt;
         GridView1.DataBind();
         b.CloseConnection();
      }
}
```

With this coding Iam unable to see Grid in output. Please help me out

Comment: Did you selected the value in dropdown which is located at 1st index? Do you get any records in response of LoadRecords function call?

Comment: yes!<asp:DropDownList ID="atddroplist" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
        onselectedindexchanged="atddroplist_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">Current Week</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Last Week</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Current Month</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Last Month</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>     iam not getting any records

Comment: If you are getting values in dt then you will definitly get value on selecting Lastweek from the dropdown. Because i tried your code with a different data source and it is working fine.

Comment: Thank u! i got the output

Answer (score 0):

We can check few things 
- AutoPostBack of dropdown is set to True 
- We are getting data in dt 
- If necessary we can put grid in the updatepanel on your page

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (atddroplist.SelectedIndex  == 1)
            {
              empatdListBI c = new empatdListBI();
      DbConnection b = new DbConnection();
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
               DataTable DT = new DataTable();
               DT = c.LoadRecords(empText.Text);
  b.OpenConnection();
               if (DT.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "PopUp", "alert(' Record Not Found...');", true);
                    txtsearchrecord.Text = "";
                    txtsearchrecord.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = DT;
                    GridView1.DataBind();                    
                }  
     b.CloseConnection();                 
            }
```